# How do I get rid of toenail fungus?

Tags: infection, treatment, treatment-options

I have had several treatments for toenail fungus where you have to file down the nail then apply a solution for weeks [about six weeks] to kill off the fungal infection. Each time it has come back again, I was given a oral treatment but I reacted to it badly with a blotchy rash.

Apart from having the toenails removed [which would be my whole left foot] what is the best way to rid yourself of this?

Comment: Moderate-to-severe fungal nail infections are difficult to treat, and [15% to 20% of successfully-treated cases relapse within a year](http://www.healthlinkbc.ca/healthtopics/content.asp?hwid=aa5527). If you have a healthy immune system and you are free of diabetes, you could [let the infection progress](http://www.healthlinkbc.ca/healthtopics/content.asp?hwid=aa5527) instead. (Every time your toenail fungus spreads beyond the nails, you should definitely cure your new case of athlete's foot. Lamisil Once film-forming solution is the most-convenient treatment option.)

Comment: Mentholated chest rub, such as Vicks VapoRub, is [useful](http://www.healthlinkbc.ca/healthtopics/content.asp?hwid=hw268101#hw268256) for treating fungal nail infections. If used nightly, it reduces the ugly appearance of the infection. It also has a mild antifungal effect, though I used it for perhaps a year and it didn't produce even a partial cure. It only provided cosmetic improvements.

Comment: If topical treatment doesn't cure your toenail fungus, and if you still want to fight the fungi, oral medications are usually the way to go. There exist quite a few options. Which oral medications have you tried? Were you allergic to all of them?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced allergies to many medications, including antibiotics, and one of the treatments (aside from abstention) has been to simultaneously take an antihistamine such as Benadryl to force the immune system not to respond to the preconceived threat.

The best way to deal with this, however, is to ask your doctor how to proceed.  An infection can get worse with less treatment, the same as none.

[Drug allergy - Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/drug-allergy/basics/definition/con-20033346)